# Rabbitmq beam.smp process utilize most of the Memory size for no reason

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

Rabbitmq beam.smp process utilize most of the Memory size for no reason

RabbitMQ version: 3.7
erlang 22

I don't have any special configuration or anything

I don't use celery or anything except Rabbitmq.

I searched for this issue and all I found is something related to celery!

What's the problem with this RabbitMQ .. it can't stand for couple of days without issues!

Comment: You need to quantify what "most of the cpu power means". What CPU(s) are available, and how are they being used. What does `top` show? What is the overall system load? "it can't stand for couple of days without issues" is also no help - you need to state exactly what the issues are.

Comment: it's Memory size not cpu .. my fault.
it utilize up to 85% of the the total memory 16Gb, before I reset the rabbitmq itself.
nothing in the machine it's fresh ubuntu 18.04 and fresh rabbitmq 3.7.

Comment: Are you publishing messages? Consuming them? At what rates? Are you using RabbitMQ's API? You're basically giving us no information to work with. RabbitMQ will not consume memory if it's not doing anything. If it is, there is something seriously wrong with your environment.

Comment: You should read [this web page](https://www.rabbitmq.com/memory-use.html) and come back with some information about your environment. I asked several questions that you aren't answering. Your initial question gives us no information other than RabbitMQ and Erlang version.

Answer (score 2):

CPU utilization could be Erratic with large number of mirrored queues.
Please mention the following RabbitMQ deployment details:

```
RabbitMQ v3.7
Erlang/OTP v22
Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Linux 4.15.0-32-generic x86_64
```

mention dstat --cpu check for RabbitMQ nodes utilization w.r.t CPU (user + system)

Additionally u can do what 
It is possible to make schedulers that currently do not have work to do using the +sbwt flag:

```
RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS="+sbwt none"
```

The value of none can reduce CPU usage on systems that have a large number of mostly idle connections.

Answer (score 1):

Several reasons can increase the CPU usage, you are not providing enough information.

What you should do is:

1. Check the rabbitmq logs, to see if there is some error
2. Check if you have some publisher that are trolling the server
3. Check the number of the queues/binding, maybe you are creating too many queues/binding

you can also enable this rabbitmq plugin https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-top to see with process is using all the CPU

Comment: I've enabled the rabbitmq-top .. I will watch it for while.